# Why can't I connect an agent to our self-hosted Azure DevOps server?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops), I created a Linux agent for an **on-premise Microsoft DevOps** installation. (The process is basically creating a directory, copying over `Dockerfile` and `start.sh` and running a `docker build -t my_agent .`, followed by a `docker run -e AZP_URL=https://my_server -e AZP_TOKEN=my_token -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=my_agent my_agent`.)
Because we are using our own certificates for the server, I adapted the dockerfile to import the certificate into the container:

```
WORKDIR /azp
COPY ./my_server.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY ./start.sh  ./
RUN update-ca-certificates && chmod +x start.sh

# ENTRYPOINT [ "/azp/start.sh" ]
```

(Copying of the certificate and running update-ca-certificates was added compared to the tutorial. I disabled the entrypoint in order to debug.)
When I now query the server with curl, it works fine:

```
curl -v https://my_server/
```

No certificate errors are reported (anymore). Running the `start.sh` script then still fails with an error:

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

When looking at the logs, this hint can be found as for the reason:

```
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

What could be the reason of this? I can't see any more precise hints as to why the remote certificate should be invalid. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

curl seems to be ok if just a certificate is imported into the system. The agent from Microsoft however needs the whole certificate chain to be available to trust the connection. To get that, the simplest way is to open a secure connection with a chrome based browser to whatever target you need, open the details of the secure connection and export root CA and intermediate certificates. (The server certificate should be presented by the server itself, Firefox doesn't seem to allow export of certificates.)

So, exchange this line:

```
COPY ./my_server.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

with this line:

```
COPY ./root-ca.crt ./intermediat-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

After that, a SSL connection should be possible. By leaving out the server certificate you should be able to test the connection with curl as it will not simply accept the certificate from the server and validates against the certification chain.